# why the chart is not display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to display this flow chart
[Can I create a flow chart (no tree chart) using D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226849/can-i-create-a-flow-chart-no-tree-chart-using-d3-js)

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/jWaEYX?editors=101
it is not display

```
var connectedObject=[
{from:'0', to:'1', label:''}, 
{from:'1', to:'3', label:''}, 
{from:'3', to:'2', label:'No'}, 
{from:'3', to:'4', label:'Yes'},
{from:'2', to:'5', label:'Yes'},
{from:'2', to:'6', label:'No'},
{from:'4', to:'7', label:'No'},
{from:'4', to:'8', label:'Yes'},
{from:'5', to:'9', label:''},
{from:'6', to:'9', label:''},
{from:'7', to:'9', label:''},
{from:'8', to:'9', label:''}
];

var objectSource={
0:{'name':'Start',color:'green'}, 
1:{'name':'Read A,B,C',color:'yellow'}, 
2:{'name':'Is B>C?',color:'green'},
3:{'name':'Is A>B?',color:'green'},
4:{'name':'Is A>C?',color:'green'},
5:{'name':'Print B',color:'green'},
6:{'name':'Print C',color:'green'},
7:{'name':'Print C',color:'green'},
8:{'name':'Print A',color:'green'},
9:{'name':'End',color:'red'}
}
```

any update?

Comment: You ripped that code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22279569/5334137) which says that, in his opinion, D3.js isn't suited to the problem and says that you need to put that code in [this website](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.3/demos/databinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html). So the code doesn't work with D3.js.

Comment: @leroydev so how I will make this ? could you help me

Comment: In the HTML source: "yFiles demo files exhibit yFiles for HTML functionalities. Any redistribution of demo files in source code or binary form, with or without modification, is not permitted.". So no, you are legally not allowed to use that library, without a license.

Comment: @leroydev how I will make that demo ? do you have any idea

Comment: ok..do you know any library to make flowchart.i want to make flowchart  in javascript ..do you know any library

Comment: Questions in which you ask for a certain library are not allowed on stackoverflow. Google can help you with questions like that.

Comment: I searched a lot but all are licenced ..could you know amything